# Django reflexive relationship

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, pymongo, djongo

I am working with MongoDB v6.0.6 and Django v4.1.9. I have a reflexive relationship in one of my models:

```py
class Learner(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='learner_supervisor')
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="learner_profile")
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="learner_company")
```

When I try to create an object in the Django admin, I encounter an issue with the error message:
`No exception message supplied`
A screenshot of the error message is available below:

[image: Error message]

I'm not sure what the cause of this issue is. Can someone provide guidance on how I can solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Please share the full tracaback as *text*, not an image.